# Python print values from json table with requests?

Tags: python, json, roblox

I just started python and can't figure out how I would do this.

So I want to make a tool that interacts with roblox.com.
I'm using requests to get something from a specific user.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.roblox.com/Groups/GetPrimaryGroupInfo.ashx?users=Shedletsky")
print r.text
```

returns

`{"Shedletsky" : {"GroupId" : 2814397, "GroupName" : "Shedletsky Studios", "RoleSetName" : "Owner", "RoleSetRank" : 255}}`

How do I interact with the json table to get only certain variables? e.g make it Print the GroupName only so in the end I would get something like:

```
Groupname: Shedletsky Studios
```

Comment: You need to change `r.text` to `r.json()` so that you convert the response directly to a python dictionary (currently it's unicode). Then you interact with it just as you would a normal dict. Something like `data = r.json()` and then `data['Shedletsky']['GroupId']` to get 2814397.

Comment: Works flawless aswell! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to extract your data from text json you need to convert it to json first, so do this

```
    import json
    r = requests.get("https://www.roblox.com/Groups/GetPrimaryGroupInfo.ashx?users=Shedletsky")
    print r.text

    data = json.load(r.text)
    print data['GroupName']
```

this will get your work done

hope this helps :)

Comment: No need for `data = json.load(r.text)`, just `data = r.json()`

Comment: and remember if you have a json array then you have to use `json.loads(r.text)`

Comment: Thanks! had to use data['Shedletsky']['GroupName'] though. Otherwise it works flawless, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Its telling me i have to wait, will do it when i can! Thanks again